# Using Tkinter to choose a file, then draw it using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying  to make a small GUI application that would allow the user to pick a .bmp file and then display the pixel values in given row (in this case 500th row) as a plot. I've managed to make the plot appear if I give it the filename before hand and I can choose a file from the DialogBox and make it print out the file name in the console but I am confused of how to to pass the file name to the function that would redraw my plot.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

f=Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a=f.add_subplot(111)

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage]=frame
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menu)
         # create the file object)
        file = tk.Menu(menu)
        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        file.add_command(label="Choose_file",command=self.load_file)


        #added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)




    def load_file(self):
        self.fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Picture files", "*.png;*.bmp"),
                                               ("All files", "*.*") ))
        print(self.fname)
        return self.fname

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):


        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button4=tk.Button(self,text="Draw!")
        button4.pack()

#This commented out section should contain a button that should call a function that would redraw the graph once the file has been chosen. 
#I am definitely doing something wrong here.

        #button5=tk.Button(self,text="Print filename!", command=self.redraw(self.fname))
        #button5.pack()



        canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)

def showmegraph(file):
    a.clear()
    p=np.fromfile(file,dtype=np.float16)
    p.shape=(1040,1392)
    a.plot(p[500])

app = MainWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

To put this together I've been trying to work off these [tutorials](http://pythonprogramming.net/embedding-live-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/?completed=/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/) where he tries to do something similar (a GUI application with matplotlib plotting) but not identical.

I would appreciate any pointers on either what should I change or what sources should I look into to solve this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific question, you asked, the answer is:

```
    def load_file(self):
        self.fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Picture files", "*.png;*.bmp"),
                                               ("All files", "*.*") ))
        print(self.fname)
        showmegraph(self.fname)
```

But there are several other problems in your code...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works! But yes, some of my colleagues who are more familiar with GUI's and OOP in Python told me all of this is rubbish. I guess I am in general confused about how Tkinter works while written as objects, but most other posts here seem to agree that it is good practice.

But this works and I thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: You're welcome. OOP in Python is not easy and Tkinter is not easy, but yes, they both are very useful tools (especially combined) once you have learnt to use them. A Tkinter tutorial (this one for example: http://usingpython.com/using-tkinter/) is highly recommended.